# Two references in the same entity to another entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the entity `User`, this entity is used twice in another entity `Product`. I use hibernate and foreign keys between tables are created. There are also two foreign keys - for create_by and modified_by.

*class User*

```
class User {

    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<ProductgetProducts{
        return this.products
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products
    }
}
```

*class Product*

```
class Product {
    private User createdBy;
    private User modifiedBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by", nullable = false)
    public User getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(User createdBy) {
        this.modifiedBy= modifiedBy;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    public User getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
}
```

It throws me this exception and I don't know how to fix it.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Product.user in User.products
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mappedBy = "user"`means: I'm the inverse side of a bidirectional association, whose owner side is the field `user` in the target entity (i.e. Product). There is no `user` field in Product. So it doesn't make sense.

If you want the `createdBy` ad `modifiedBy` associations to be bidirectional, you need two fields in User:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy")
private Set<Product> createdProducts;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "modifiedBy")
private Set<Product> modifiedProducts;
```